# SQL Server - Many to Many query into 1 row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables

**Movies:**

- Movie_id
- Title
- Runtime
- Date_id
- ...

**Genre:**

- Genre_id
- Genre

**Movie_Genre:**

- Movie_id
- Genre_id

I want to put them in one row so that each genre is separated by a column
like this:

```
Movie_id | Title | Genre1 | Genre2 | Genre3 | Genre4 |
```

Each movie may or may not have up to 4 genres.

I came close with this approach:

```
SELECT
    Movies.Movie_id,
    MAX(Movies.Title),
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=1 THEN p.Genre_id END) as Genre1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=2 THEN p.Genre_id END) as Genre2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=3 THEN p.Genre_id END) as Genre3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=4 THEN p.Genre_id END) as Genre4
FROM 
    Movies
JOIN
    (SELECT 
         Movie_Genre.*,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Movie_id ORDER BY Genre_id) AS RowNum
     FROM 
         Movie_Genre) AS P ON Movies.Movie_id = p.Movie_id
GROUP BY  
    Movies.movie_id
```

But I end up with the `Genre_id` instead of the Genre name.

Also the title column is not named

Comment: sample data and output will do our life much more easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INNER JOIN to the Genre table in the sub query

```
select  Movies.Movie_id,
        Movies.Title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=1 THEN p.Genre END) as Genre1,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=2 THEN p.Genre END) as Genre2,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=3 THEN p.Genre END) as Genre3,
        MAX(CASE WHEN p.RowNum=4 THEN p.Genre END) as Genre4
FROM    Movies
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT  mg.Movie_id, g.Genre,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY mg.Movie_id ORDER BY mg.Genre_id) 
                as RowNum
        FROM    Movie_Genre mg
                INNER JOIN Genre g  on  mg.Genre_id = g.Genre_id
    ) as P  ON Movies.Movie_id=p.Movie_id
GROUP BY Movies.movie_id, Movies.Title
```

Comment: needed a comma after g.genre on line 10, but other than that it worked. Thanks a lot.